# Uploading/Arduino gets an error : permission denied on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have faced this problem for few years ago and I solved it on Ubuntu 14.04 but I don't know why my solution doesn't work right now on Ubuntu 16.04

The Error:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied
```

I'm using the same solution from [The guide](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload) , by searching for solution on Stack sites and more ...

Here what I've done :

```
ls -l /dev/ttyACM*
```

from the result : The owner is **root** and the
group with access is **dialout**

Then I applied:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout <username>
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0
```

Finally logged out and logged in.

Sompe people said they've solved it by removing modemmanager so I have tried that as well :

```
sudo apt-get remove modemmanager
```

But after all , the problem hasn't solved yet

Note: Arduino Uno with Ubuntu 16.04

Edited:
After apply :

```
ls -l /dev/ttyACM*
```

The result is :

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Jan 10 13:33 /dev/ttyACM0
```

Comment: If you run `groups`, are you a member of the `dialout` group? Does `/dev/ttyACM0` actually allow *write* access to the `dialout` group? Update your question to show the *output* of `ls -l /dev/ttyACM*`, and the output of the `groups` command.

Comment: @larsks Yes I am already member , I updated it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (as you already figured out), that your user is not allowed to access the `/dev/ttyACM0` device.
You have several possibilities:

1. temporarily fix the issue for your current session

   ```
   sudo chown <user>:<group> /dev/ttyACM0
   ```

   This changes the ownership of the file to *user* and the group to *group*
   (**note:** you will have to do this again, as soon as you replug your arduino)
2. permanently fix the issue for each session

   you create a **udev-rule** for your arduino and put it into `/etc/udev/rules.d` (you should be able to find a correct udev-rule for your arduino when googling for it).

   The trivial approach would be the following udev-rule:

   **99-arduino.rules**

   ```
   KERNEL=="ttyACM0",GROUP="plugdev"
   ```

   please be aware that now every `/dev/ttyACM0` device will be owned by the group "plugdev" (or whatever group you specify). This might not be, what you really want. So please read into udev-rules how to specify your arduino-device exclusively (hint: vendorID and productID)

Comment: I hoped that works , but still have the same error , it's so confused I try ti fix it for 2 weeks ago , but I could find no solution , any suggestion ?

Comment: assuming your user is `john` ... if you enter `sudo chown john:john /dev/ttyACM0`, then `ls -la /dev/ttyACM0` should show you that the ownership changed ... right?

If you then couldn't access the ttyACM0-device, then it maybe is blocked by another process?

Comment: All I need from this thing that getting " moh dialout " it means moh already member of " dialout " so what's going on !! should be worked ! 
there is no another process !!

Comment: if the device is owned by the user (and the user is in the group, the device belongs to) then you must be able to open it. try `cat /dev/ttyACM0` just to make sure you have read permissions on the device. if that does not work, give it a try with `sudo` (does it work, when you start your arduino-IDE as root?!)